# Alternative to spyOn().and.callfake in Jestjs

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I used to have `spyOn().and.callFake` in jasmine and it helps a lot in my tests, now I'm using Jest, I've found in the doc that `jest.spyOn()` exist but without the `callFake`.

My Question: How to spy on a method and call Fake with Jest and `expect`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[jest.spyOn official documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname) gives a great answer:

> Note: By default, jest.spyOn also calls the spied method. This is
> different behavior from most other test libraries. If you want to
> overwrite the original function, you can use jest.spyOn(object,
> methodName).mockImplementation(() => customImplementation) or
> object[methodName] = jest.fn(() => customImplementation);

So in your case just pass a fake method to `customImplementation`.

Comment: yes it was this, but it's best to use `jest.fn().mockImplementation(()=> stuff)` instead of spyon

Comment: For `jest.fn()` you don't need `.mockImplementation()` chain. Just pass implementation function directly to `jest.fn(()=> stuff)`